# how to read facebook profile timeline feed with Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am using Facebook [PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) v5 with Facebook Graph API v2.10 and by other code i am able to get data from facebook page easily, but what i need is to fetch data of user profile wall , 
from [facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) i am able to read those data by generating token. but not by code.

it will throwing error

> URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.

and i have used localhost url in the app oAuth setting as well,
I wanted to read someones wall post feed after authorize him by my applications, i dont want to read my own profile like `api('/me/feed'`
 does anyone help me in this case.

Comment: /me/feed is still correct for other user profiles, you just need to use a user token with the user_posts permission of that user.

Comment: _“does anyone help me in this case”_ - yes, the search engine of your choice does, all you need to do is feed it the error message.

Comment: +1 @luschn but i am getting error that i have posted, can't i use http://localhost/fb/getusertoken.php file there ? or i just wanted the user to authenticate my app once and i will read his feed on my application although he is offline.

Comment: You can use that, but you must make the required settings in the app dashboard first ...

Comment: also read about extended access tokens in the docs

Comment: Thanks i am able to get userprofile posts data but it only for my profile, if someone authorize app by their account it only shows id and name. rather than full user_posts data. how can i achieve this ?

Comment: As i can see I do not submitted my app for review to FB because `user_posts` needs review after submission, is that the right reason ?